# How to convert an array to PGLint (ie:^integer) in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have this openGL function declared in delphi :

```
PGLint = ^GLint;
GLint = Integer;
glTexParameteriv(target, pname: GLenum; params: PGLint);
```

in the sample i found on the web this function must be call like this :

```
int crop_rect[4] = {x, y, width, height};
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, crop_rect);
```

However i don't know how to translate the crop_rect in delphi ? especially how to pass it to glTexParameteriv ?

Comment: I think you're using [this library](https://github.com/maerlyn/old-delphi-codes/blob/master/3DSZOVEG/OpenGL.pas)? Looks like crop_rect is expected to be an array of integer, or more simply put, a buffer of the size of 4 integers. You pass the pointer to the first integer (i.e. the start of the buffer) to the function. I guess the library has functions to initialize such a buffer, although I couldn't find it on first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var
  crop_rect: array [0..3] of GLint ;
....
crop_rect[0] := x;
crop_rect[1] := y;
crop_rect[2] := width;
crop_rect[3] := height;
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, @crop_rect[0]);
```

Comment: it's look this, but i don't understand why it's crash :( i will investigate a little more deeper

Comment: The code here is, as far as I can see, a direct translation of the C code. Problem is probably in the arguments supplied. Have you checked the documentation.